# $Epilog does not work when exit

Tags: evaluation, kernel

The following code does work:

```
  $Epilog := Print@1;
   Quit[];
```

But if I close the document and exit WM or click QuitKernel, it does not work. Why?

Comment: My guess is that for both of the two methods you mentioned last, the `$Epilog` hook is not triggered, because they quit the kernel via a different route. Presumably because they both are initiated by the Front End. Let's wait for someone with a deeper knowledge of this mechanism to comment on this.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It may be possible to somehow implement code execution if the exit of other methods?

Comment: It might be possible, but that would require the knowledge of the specific Front End hooks, which would need to be defined instead of `$Epilog`, provided that such hooks exist (if they exist, I am not aware of them).