# Best practice to persist symbols between sessions and a problem with $Epilog

Tags: kernel, persistence

I often define functions like this in my notebooks:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_, b_, c_] := f[a, b, c] = f[b, a, c] = somethingExpensive[a, b, c]
```

where I use memoization to store the results of some long computations. When I restart the Kernel, I want to avoid re-computing these expressions by default.

What is the best way to achieve my goal of persisting symbols with minimal code cluttering?

Comment: change `= somethingExpensive[a, b, c]` to `= Once[somethingExpensive[a, b, c], "Local"]`.  See [Caching result of evaluation in the notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280701/9490)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Never mind my brittle implementation. I'll delete my partial answer and create a new question about the $Epilog problem - just for completeness.

Comment: Ah, and the $Epilog thing is already discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66005/epilog-does-not-work-when-exit).